# I need to update image for specific user Django

Tags: python, django, backend

I need to update image for specific user Django . Now if I updating the image  for specific user , image updates for all users . Is there any solutions ? Here is my code :

**models.py**

```
class UserWithImage(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    image=models.FileField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/',null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**views.py**

```
if 'imagechange' in request.POST and request.FILES['image']:
    image = request.FILES['image']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    image_fs = fs.save(image.name, image)
    image_new = UserWithImage.objects.update(image=image_fs)
```

**html page**

```
    <form  id='myform' enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}               
        <input type="file" class="settings__background__file" name="image" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="backgroundimage" placeholder="Upload image">
    <button id="submit-image" name="imagechange" type="submit"> Upload Image </button>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you have to filter your queryset. You are currently updating all objects.

```
image_new = UserWithImage.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(image=image_fs)
```

or if you do not want to update the user which does the request you call it like

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
image_new = UserWithImage.objects.filter(user=user).update(image=image_fs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to select the user and then update the image. But after this, **remember to remove the old image**, it would still be stored in your media folder, even if it was replaced.

Here is how i would do it

```py
if 'imagechange' in request.POST and request.FILES['image']:
    image = request.FILES['image']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    image_fs = fs.save(image.name, image)
    user_with_image = UserWithImage.objects.get(user=request.user)
    # get the old image path
    old_image_path = user_with_image.image.path
    #replace the image and save
    user_with_image.image = image_fs
    user_with_image.save()

    # delete the old image
    if os.path.exists(old_image_path):
        os.remove(old_image_path)
```